# How to get the IP of a domain in ssl/tls socket connection using python

Tags: sockets, ssl, networking, network-programming, tls1.2

I need to record the IP address of the domain name that make successful TLS connection. This is a simplified code:

```
import socket, ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext() 
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE 
context.check_hostname = False 

mycipher = "DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA"
context.set_ciphers(mycipher) 
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
domain = "google.com"
mySocket = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname = domain) 
mySocket.connect((domain, 443))
mySocket.close()
```

How can I get the IP in such a way that if the connection succeeds, I get the IP. If not, I do not want to record the IP.

I find some functions to get the selected TLS version `version()` and the selected ciphersuite `cipher()` in a TLS session, which is always retrieves a value when the connection succeeds. But nothing I found about getting the IP. I know they may be different things (the version and cipher are related to the TLS session and the IP is related to the connection) but I do not want to record IPs for non successful TLS connections. Only when the connection succeeds, I want to record the IP (e.g. store it in a variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address is a TCP/IP property, not a TLS one.

Hence you should look into what is given by the `socket` module.

For example you have:

> socket.getpeername()
>
> ```
> Return the remote address to which the socket is connected.
> ```
>
> This is useful to find out the port number of a remote IPv4/v6 socket, for
>   instance. (The format of the address returned depends on the address
>   family — see above.) On some systems this function is not supported.

Comment: I think `socket.gethostbyname([hostname])` is what I should use.

Comment: This is a generic function to resolve any name you want to resolve. This is not (necessarily) the one used by your specific `sock` connection in your code. If you want, outside of any connection, to resolve an hostname, use `socket.getaddrinfo()` instead